# What microphone is used in these videos?

Tags: microphone, filter

What microphone (and mount) does this girl use in her videos?

Examples:

- 
- 
- 

Also:  Would using a pop filter help her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to add that she has very pleasing tone and natural voice.

After careful visual inspection, I am pretty certain that this is an AKG Perception 220 Condenser mic.

The mount comes with it, at least at this site:

http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/akg-perception-220-condenser-microphone

"Spider-type shock mount and metal case included"

[image]

A Pop Filter is generally a good idea, but she is not on top of the mic as she is back a bit playing the keyboard, so in her case a pop filter probably will not make any difference. However, in the Elton John tune she is on top of the mic and I really don't hear any objectionable pops, she has her "puffs" right.
:>

Comment: It's very hard to tell whether she's got a 120 or 220 since the bodies are almost identical. Both are condensers, which need power via their XLR connectors. Power can be supplied by a mixer. An alternative is the Perception 120 USB. Like its name suggests, it has a USB connector which can plug right into your computer. No extra power needed.

Comment: When I did my visual examination I noted that the 220 has a slight gold tone to the mic screen which is consistent with the target where as the 120 has an aluminum tone screen.

Comment: is it possible the microphone alone made the difference between "Pray" and "ET" ? Suddenly there is a very noticeable difference .

Comment: @OlivierS I don't think she used this microphone for either of the videos you've mentioned. In E.T. she used a different camera though, and probably the camera-mic, if that's what you meant.